# The Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ about $a=3$?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm having difficulty calculating the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ about $a=3$, and was wondering if anyone on here could help me out.

Here's what I've tried so far:

**Attempt 1 -** Take $y=x-3$ and rearrange as $x=y+3$.

Then do $\frac{1}{1-x}=\frac{1}{1-(y+3)}=\frac{1}{-y-2}=\frac{-1}{y+2}=\frac{-1}{1+(y+1)}$.

Now, knowing $\frac{-1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}x^n$, I write $\frac{-1}{1+(y+1)}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(y+1)^n$.

We change now and get $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(y+1)^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}((x-3)+1)^n$.

And then simplify and get our final result which is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(x-2)^n$.

**Attempt 2 -** Recall first the formal definition of a Taylor series centered about $x=a$;

the formal definition is as I remember $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(n)}(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n$.

Take $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}$.

Now, I see that $f'(x)=\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}$, $f''(x)=\frac{2}{(1-x)^3}$, ..., $f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{n!}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$.

Replacing $x$ as $a$ I get now $f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{(1-a)^{n+1}}$.

Taking $a=3$, we write $f^{(n)}(a)=\frac{n!}{(1-a)^{n+1}}=f^{(n)}(3)=\frac{n!}{(1-3)^{n+1}}=f^{(n)}(3)=\frac{n!}{(-2)^{n+1}}$.

By the formal definition we now write $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\frac{n!}{(-2)^{n+1}}}{n!}(x-3)^n$.

Simplifying the above we get the end result $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-3)^n}{(-2)^{n+1}}$.

My attempts gave me two completely different answers. What gives? Is there something I'm doing wrong in either attempt? Is there something I'm doing wrong in both?

Help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Often useful as a check if you get different results to try something like putting $x=3.1$ and write out the series and see which one gives the best approximation to the actual answer. Always easy to do this on a spreadsheet if you want to cheat (spreadsheets can be great for numerical calculations/tests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first attempt is wrong, because after you do the substitution $y=x-3$, you should aim at a power series about $0$, not about $-1$.

Your second attempt is corect (but I would put $(-1)^n$ in the numerator and $2^n$ in the denominator).

Comment: Ah, okay I see now. To clarify though, what do you mean by looking to aim at a power series about $0$ not $1$?? Sorry, still sort of confused on the whole matter.

Comment: @Kianlos I was talking about the center of the power series: the $a$ in $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$.

Answer (score 2):

As already said above, your first attempt is incorrect. But it's easy to do it correctly: for $|y|<2$,

$$\frac{1}{1-(y+3)}=-\frac{1}{2+y}=-\frac12\frac{1}{1+\frac{y}2}=-\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{y^n}{2^n}$$

Comment: Sorry, but when would I know exactly how to do it this way? I'm still having trouble understanding why my first attempt's algebra manipulation is incorrect and how yours isn't. I see that yours gives the answer I got in attempt 2, but don't really know why...

Comment: José Carlos Santos already answered to that: when writing $\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^nx^n$, you must have $|x|<1$.